Boot Persistent USB to ram in Read only mode to use with USB unplugged
Need to be able to boot an Ubuntu USB with persistence and make changes to the OS, and then when needed, have an option in grub that boots the system to ram with said changes loaded so that i can unplug the usb while the live OS is running. I do not need the system to be persistent when booting in toram mode. How would i go about getting this done?
Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, live install created with rufus with persistence
Better way of explaining it: Need to setup a live boot USB with 2 Boot options in grub
Option 1: Boot the USB normally with persistence
Option 2: Boot the USB toram without persistence (But with any apps / system changes ive made when booting with persistence)
Option 2 would be used so that the OS can be used unplugged from the PC

I'd create an updated system using 22.04.4 as if you're using 22.04.3 you're behind on applying security fixes (and using a kernel from 23.04 which is EOL & thus unpached if using HWE). The mkusb program documents the toram option, but sorry I'm not a user of rufus.

mkusb can do what im looking for?
